# thinkpad t460 (intel 8260) wifi instability

Tags: networking, drivers, thinkpad

My thinkpad is constantly dropping wifi connection, despite appearing to still be connected. I'm at my wit's end trying to stabilize my wifi. I've tried fedora 25, Ubuntu 16.04, and Ubuntu 16.10. I've done everything I've seen on the internet from trying backports firmware, disabling N band internet, and turning off wifi power management, but the wifi is still dropping. Does anybody else have this issue with their intel 8260ac/thinkpad t460? How do I know if my wifi card is definitely faulty versus router problems?

Comment: is it your router?